# Постановка запятых в сложноподчиненном предложении с частицей ЛИ

Tags: пунктуация, спп

**При этом, ссылаясь на специфику залогового имущества, заявитель жалобы указывает на то, что при реализации мясной продукции будет невозможно определить, произведена ли она из залогового имущества.**

Сомневаюсь в постановке запятой после слова *определить*:

**определить(,) произведена ли...**

Каким правилом регламентируется?

Answer (score 3):

...невозможно **определить** (что?), произведена **ли** она из залогового имущества.

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненной части предложении с придаточным изъяснительным, здесь функцию союза выполняет **вопросительная частица ЛИ.**